# Make an http post request to send a json file in Blackberry OS < 7.X

Tags: json, post, blackberry, httprequest

I would like to send a JSON file from my BB device to my local server. On iOS I used the ASIHttpRequest library and what I did was :

```
//send json file , using ASIHttpClass
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.timeOutSeconds = TIME_OUT_SECONDS;
[request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

NSString *credentials= [self encodeCredentials];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Authorization" value:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Basic %@",credentials]];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];        

[request appendPostData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request startSynchronous];

if([request responseStatusCode]==200){
   return true;
} else {
     return false;
    }
```

How could I implement the same functionality in my BlackBerry OS < 7.X  application?